# python fileinput module reset position

Tags: python, file, file-io

I need to loop over a file twice. First time check if there are some key words.
Second time append some info to the file according to previous checking result.

I use fileinput module so I can have a `fileinput.lineno()` to decide which line to append my info.

typical use of fileinput is

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

So I have to open the file twice.

My file is something like this

```
#define XXX YYYY     ------->at least one #define in my file
extern int AW_Function1();   --------> may have many AW functions or no AW functions
extern int AW_Function2();
extern int AW_Function3();
```

There are Functions with AW key word or totally no AW functions in my file.I need to check this with my code.

This is what I have

```
for line in fileinput.input('file1.txt'):
    if '#define' in line:   # there is at least one '#define' in that file
        writePoint = fileinput.lineno() + 1                  
    elif 'AW' in line:
        writePoint = fileinput.lineno() + 1 

for line in fileinput.input('file1.txt'):
    if writePoint == fileinput.lineno() :
        ###generate a new line here
        print new_line
    print line,
```

file object returned by `open` don't provide a line number and have a `fseek` function for re-positioning while `fileinput` module have a line number but don't have a `fseek` function.

Is there a better way to do this with only one file open?

Comment: `.seek(1024)` doesn't work? I'd also use `os.open()` or simply `open()` instead.

Comment: @Torxed open() doesn't give you a line number and I have to count the lines.

Comment: So why not do: `row_counter = 0` and then `with open('file.txt', 'r') as fh:` and then `for line in fh:` and simply do `row_counter += 1`? It's exactly the same thing as the pre-defined function you're using is doing, only differenace is that you write the code instead of relying on someone elses module/code. :)

Comment: @Torxed you are right.If there is no better way to do this I'll take it.

Comment: there are some Wizards here on SO, so might be a neater solution out there. Best of luck.